# TypeScript: Find all combinations (with repetition) of an array of numbers that results in a sum greater than or equal to k

Tags: typescript, combinations

I am trying to make a function that has 2 arguments: An array of integers and a single integer "sum"
The goal is to find all possible combinations of the numbers in the array (with repetition) that results in a sum greater than or equal to *k*

In pseudo:

```
function getCombinations(numbers: number[], sum: number): Array<{index: number, combination: Array<number>}> {
    //combination calculation & return nested array with valid combinations
}
```

Something that would work like this

```
let numbers: number[] = [4, 5, 14, 24, 28, 70, 220, 440];
let k: number = 400;

console.log(getCombinations(numbers, k));
```

For example:

[220, 220]

[220, 70, 440]

[440]

[5, 5, 5, .....]

.... etc

Basically all the combinations that reach the "threshold" of 400

Comment: You don’t say that the integers are positive, nor do you say that the output arrays must remain below the threshold until the final element.  Without these restrictions or something like them, the output would be an infinite set of arrays. Could you [edit] the question to specify your requirements more exactly? It would also be nice to have an actual question in there, as well as any evidence of your attempts /research and what their pitfalls were.

Comment: Oof even with these restrictions the number of outputs for your example seems unimaginably huge.  You are allowing `[220, 70, 440]` as a separate output from, say, `[70, 220, 440]`.  There's a relatively short implementation to calculate this according to my suggested restrictions, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mb0kbw), but it's not feasible to calculate for the example you've given.  Even with caching intermediate results like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAy7Xm) it takes forever with your example.  What, specifically, are you looking for, here?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry about the wording in my post, I wasn't really sure how to put into words what I was trying to accomplish. The example you posted was actually exactly what I was looking for but you are correct that the amount of combinations using smaller numbers is massive. 
I will try to explain in better detail because now I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible:

Comment: Basically I have an array of numbers and each number has another assigned value like so (using the example numbers):

`4: 50`
`5: 60`
`14: 120`
`24: 200`
`70: 480`
`220: 1400`
`440: 2200`

`sum for first number >= 400`

I am trying to get all the combinations of the first number that is greater than or equal to a sum k and then find which of those combinations has the smallest sum of the second numbers added together

For example:
`[220, 220]: 1400 + 1400 = 2800`

`[220, 70, 440]: 1400 + 480 + 2200 = 4080`

`[440]: 2200: 2200 //this is the "solution"`

Comment: Hmm, well, that's different.  You're talking about a variant of [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  You could maybe solve it [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mLl9Zm) but you'd need to test against your use cases.  As stated this question is unfortunately an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where your actual issue is the knapsack-like question but you asked about generating *all possible combinations* which is not viable.  Could you [edit] the question to ask about your actual issue instead of an untenable approach?